# How to set a gameobject to an exact length in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have a float that represents a distance

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(start.position,end.position);
```

I want to use that float to change the size of an object along its Z axis. I tried:

```
gameobject.transform.localScale.z = distance;
```

However, this just changes the scale, I need to change the game object to an exact length. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Not really. Your best bet would be to give the object you're going to scale a size of 1 unit. Other than that, there is no object length concept in Unity.

Comment: Yes scale is only property that can be used to define length, width, height of a gameObject. However you can assign its collider's property in other ways.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created a workaround function to convert a specific length into a scale (for anyone who may find this question in the future). Game objects can only have their size changed though scale, but their exact size can be found through the renderer. using a little interpolation you can convert this into a new scale to resize your object to an exact size.

```
public void newScale(GameObject theGameObject, float newSize) {

    float size = theGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.y;

    Vector3 rescale = theGameObject.transform.localScale;

    rescale.y = newSize * rescale.y / size;

    theGameObject.transform.localScale = rescale;

}
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. My object was parented to another object and it was rotated.

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 it is because he is just modifying the y axis. If you want it to work for every axis you have to modify the function to your needs

Comment: @RayYago yes, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/54264294/2336212

Answer (score 1):

Unity has no thing like "Length" for any object. At the scale of (1,1,1) unity considers that every object is of one unit. meaning if you want your object to be 3 units long along z axis you change its scale to (1,1,3) and similarly for other axis. thats why it is said that you need to take special care while designing assets for unity as they all need to made according to unity defined scale.

Comment: The issue is that this will be in a nested hierarchy, so the scale is based on the parent. SO I need to abstract from that. I also dont know how to convert a distance into "units" anyway. Especially seeing as the unit is arbitrary depending on which primitive has been instantiated. scale 1 for capsule is different to scale 1 for cubes etc.

Comment: A cube is even on all sides so unity will consider them all equal to 1 unit. in case of capsule. hight is greater than width so unity will consider the height as 1 unit and treat width according to the difference to height.

Comment: for child parent relationship you will have to separately apply the scale change to the child so that it does not disturbs the other objects. for distance to unit conversion problem you can try your own `gameobject.transform.localScale.z = distance;` method or use the one mentioned in your own answer

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand Units in Unity are definitely not arbitrary and definitely do not vary between objects. Neither is generic units unique to Unity. It is common in software from 3DS max to Maya to anything to have generic units. Scale for primitives will equate to exact length. For imported assets and textures you will need to set the scale of the importer to a value that will result in a scale of 1 being exactly 1 unit in world space. When you have done that then the scaling solution will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked better for me:

```
public void convertDistanceToScale(GameObject go, float distance){
     Vector2 size = go.transform.lossyScale;
     size.x = distance;
     size.x = (size.x * go.transform.localScale.x) / go.transform.lossyScale.x;
     size.y = go.transform.localScale.y;
     go.transform.localScale = size;
}
```

This works for all objects I've tested it on, including child objects and rotated objects.

Answer (score 0):

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBfwE.png)

in my case , this object Radius 243.638 at 3dsmax .

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p115P.png)

but this re-scale cause this is child object .
and want fix the width as parent object variable .

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnU74.png)

```
    Transform Truck_Area_Range = transform.Find("Circle");
    Mesh mesh = Truck_Area_Range.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    float Mesh_X = mesh.bounds.size.x;
    Debug.Log(Mesh_X); // this same as my 3dsmax Radius * 2
    Vector3 LocalScale = transform.localScale;
    Debug.Log(LocalScale.x); // parent object LocalScale
    float current_size = Mesh_X * LocalScale.x;
    Debug.Log(current_size); // Circle object size in scene
    float distance = 30;
    float newSize = distance / current_size;
    Debug.Log(newSize);  
    Truck_Area_Range.localScale = new Vector3 (newSize, newSize, 1);
```